# Script to parse, delete & mask IP addresses

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a CSV file with 3 columns:

- Column 1- **Overall value** - which is concatenation of *ID_IP address* [51515151  99.999.999.999]
- Column 2-  **Time Column**   - *Time* [2019-02-25T19:04:59.999-0500]
- Column 3- **IP Address (IPv4 & IPv6**) - *IP* [99.999.999.999]

I am trying to parse the IDs from the first column by splitting it into two columns with IDs and IP addresses, then discarding the column with the newly created IP addresses, since they are already contained in column 3.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
df1= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\[redacted]\\Documents\\Python\\Parsing.csv')
df1.dropna(inplace = True) # dropping null value columns to avoid errors
df1 = df1["Overall Value"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True) # updating data frame with split value columns
df1["ID"]= df1[0] # making seperate ID column from new data frame
df1["IP2"]= df1[1] # making seperate IP column from new data frame
df1["Time"]= df1[2]
df1["IP"]= df1[3]
df1.drop(columns =["IP2"], inplace = True) # deleting column 2
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\[redacted]\\Documents\\Python\\Parsingcopy.csv', index_col=0)
df1 = df1.map(df2)
df1.to_csv('C:\\Users\\[redacted]\\Documents\\Python\\Parsingcopy2.csv')
```

Why is it giving me the following error?

```
C:\Users\[Redacted]>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\[Redacted]\Documents\Python\Parsing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\[Redacted]\Documents\Python\Parsing.py", line 21, in <module>
    df1["RestofData"]= df1[2]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

> ```
> df1 = df1["Overall Value"].str.split(...)
> ```

you are not *updating* the existing dataframe, but creating a new one and pointing the `df1` name to it.

`df1` now no longer refers to the original dataframe, so `df[2]` (and `df[3]`) do not exist, which is what `KeyError: 2` is telling you.

Instead, you should use a different name for the temporary dataframe, and then use that to update the columns in the original one.

Also, instead of first creating two new columns, only to discard one of them right away, you should simply only use the one you actually want.

For the remaining columns that already exist, you should use indices 1 and 2 instead of 2 and 3, but since they are already contained in `df1` it should not be necessary to "re-insert" them.

Something like this:

```
ids_ips = df1["Overall Value"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
df1["ID"] = ids_ips[0]
# df1["IP2"] = ids_ips[1]  <-- don't do this
df1["Time"] = df1[1]  # this is probably not necessary, too
df1["IP"] = df1[2]    # neither is this
```

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 I updated my script. The new file is still blank, could you review and let me know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: `import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
data = pd.read_csv ('C:\\Users\\[Redacted]\\Documents\\Python\\[Redacted]_Sample_1.csv')
data.dropna(inplace = True) 
new = data["Overall Value"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True) 
data["ID"]= new[0]
data["IP"]= new[1]
data["Time"]= new[2]
data.drop(columns =["Overall Value"], inplace = True) 
new.to_csv(r'C:\\Users\\[Redacted]\\Documents\\Python\\[Redacted]_Sample_2.csv')`

Comment: That would be a new question, consider posting it separately.

Comment: I also recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)